# Bigquery LoadJobConfig Delete Source Files After Transfer

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

When creating a Bigquery Data Transfer Service Job Manually through the UI, I can select an option to delete source files after transfer. When I try to use the CLI or the Python Client to create on-demand Data Transfer Service Jobs, I do not see an option to delete the source files after transfer. Do you know if there is another way to do so? Right now, my Source URI is `gs://<bucket_path>/*`, so it's not trivial to delete the files myself.

Answer (score 1):

For me works this snippet (replace **YOUR-...** with your data):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
import os


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "YOUR-CRED-FILE-PATH"


transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()


destination_project_id = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
destination_dataset_id = "YOUR-DATASET-ID"


transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(
    destination_dataset_id=destination_dataset_id,
    display_name="YOUR-TRANSFER-NAME",
    data_source_id="google_cloud_storage",
    params={
        "data_path_template":"gs://PATH-TO-YOUR-DATA/*.csv",
        "destination_table_name_template":"YOUR-TABLE-NAME",
        "file_format":"CSV",
        "skip_leading_rows":"1",
        "delete_source_files": True
    },
)


transfer_config = transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
    parent=transfer_client.common_project_path(destination_project_id),
    transfer_config=transfer_config,
)
print(f"Created transfer config: {transfer_config.name}")
```

In this example, table **YOUR-TABLE-NAME** must already exist in BigQuery, otherwise the transfer will crash with error **"Not found: Table YOUR-TABLE-NAME"**.

I used this packages:

```
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer>=3.4.1
google-cloud-bigquery>=2.31.0
```

Pay attention to the attribute **delete_source_files** in **params**. From [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer):

> - Optional param **delete_source_files** will delete the source files after each successful transfer. (Delete jobs do not retry if the first effort to delete the source files fails.) The default value for the **delete_source_files** is **false**.

Comment: If you can, don't use service account key file, it could be a security hole.